# Squiggles mocking polynomials in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw squiggles in Ti*k*Z to mock the plot of polynomials?

[image]

Comment: Ti*k*Z understands commands like `\draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1] ({2*\x+0.4*cos(\x*200)},{-0.7*sin(\x*540)});` that draw something like your "randomized" plots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
\foreach \X  [count=\Y] in {green!60!black,yellow!80!orange,red}
{\draw[\X] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1,smooth] ({2*\x},{0.7*sin(\x*540)+0.4*\x+2*(2-\Y)});}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,local bounding box=right]
\foreach \X  [count=\Y] in {green!60!black,yellow!80!orange,red}
{\draw[\X] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1,smooth]
({2.5*\x+0.5*cos(\x*200)},{-0.7*sin(\x*540)+2*(2-\Y)});}
\end{scope}
\path (left.east) -- (right.west) 
node[midway,font=\sffamily,single arrow, draw]{randomize};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There are so much I don't know about tikz...

Comment: @qweruiop I guess you are in good company because I think that this statement applies to everyone but at most 5 people (Till Tantau and a few others).